# Check/uncheck checkbox when input field (textbox) has a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to clear the value of an input field (textbox) when the user unchecks a checkbox.

When the user types in the field, I want to check the checkbox.

Edit:
Funny how you get downvotes for doing exactly what StackOverflow recommends:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: What have you tried? What are the problems that you encountered during solving this task and what can we help in overcoming them? Having >3k reputation, you cannot be considered a rookie, so you should know what makes an appropriate question on SO.

Comment: Dude, I answered my own question to share my solution.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: There is no problem with answering your own question at all, you misunderstand. The problem is asking a question that does not meet the quality requirements of SO. If a rookie asked this same question, it would already be mass-downvoted and closed - for a reason. Answering it yourself makes absolutely no difference.

Comment: You should really apologize for being so quick to shoot someone down, its so annoying when someone makes unjustified comments.

Comment: The question explains the requirements clearly imho, especially considering the answer (containing code samples and everything) was posted at the same time.

Comment: Why should I post in the question things "I have tried" and "problems I encountered" when I already know the answer? That's just ridiculous.

Comment: The fact that an answer was posted at the same time does not make the question any better. I still say: a rookie posting the same question would get "What have you tried?", "This is not a site to do your job instead of you." and even worse comments - and the comments would be right. I see no reason to make a difference here just because you have more rep and can answer your own question.

Comment: I have nothing more to say. I gave my votes, told my reasons - I accept whatever happens now.

Comment: Next time you can just edit the damn question instead of making smartass comments.
Really, do it. Make the question better. Perhaps you can copy paste my answer into the question, remove a line or introduce a bug in some other way. I'm sure that will make this question more usable for future visitors.

Comment: Congratulations on your comment :).

Comment: @kapa I agree with Thomas Stock. SO is the perfect avenue for this type of question. Many future visitors will find value in the answers given.

Answer (score 1):

With this HTML:

```
<input id="thecheckbox" type="checkbox">
<input id="theinput" type="text">
```

You can use this javascript:

```
$("#theinput").keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $("#thecheckbox").prop("checked", false);
    } else {
        $("#thecheckbox").prop("checked", true);
    }
});

$("#thecheckbox").change(function () {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#theinput").val("");
    }
});
```

It works when using the keyboard for tabbing and/or checking the checkbox.

http://jsfiddle.net/B39Yq/

Comment: Within the eventhandler for the checkbox, instead of `$(this).is(':checked')` you can simply use `this.checked)`

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<input id="text"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="check"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#text").keyup(function(){
    $("#check").get(0).checked = !!$(this).val().trim();
});

$("#check").click(function(){
    (this.checked) ? "":$("#text").val("");
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/p5u64/1/

Comment: Would it not be a good idea to store the value of the checkbox so that you can bring back the value if you've typed something in the text-field and then uncheck and re-check the checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

```
function onKeyUp(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  if (target.nodeName && target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "input") {
    if (target.type && target.type == "text") {
      changeCheckboxes(this, target.value)
    }
  }
}

function onChange(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  if (target.nodeName && target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "input") {
    if (target.type && target.type == "checkbox" && !this.checked) {
      clearTextfields(this);
    }
  }
}

function clearTextfields(form) {
  var elements = form.elements;
  for (i = elements.length; i--;) {
    if (elements[i].type === "text") {
      elements[i].value = "";
    }
  }
}

function changeCheckboxes(form, check) {
  var elements = form.elements;
  for (i = elements.length; i--;) {
    if (elements[i].type === "checkbox") {
      elements[i].checked = check;
    }
  }
}

var form = document.forms[0];
form.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp);
form.addEventListener("change", onChange);
form.addEventListener("click", onChange);
```